# About foreign key and index cluster in sql / knexjs

Tags: sql, typescript, knex.js

Hello I have a little question about foreign key:

I have my table employee where I have my **ID as uuid**, and my **MATRICULA** number (it's something unique, only one per employee), and in my departments table I would like to use my manager_Id foreign key and reference my **MATRICULA** field .

But I don't know if this is correct in terms of sql, that is, it references a field that is not primary in a foreign key relationship

my table employee:

```
export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  return knex.schema.hasTable('employee').then(function (exists) {
    if (exists) return;
    return knex.schema // **** udpate
      .createTable('employees', table => {
        table.uuid('id').notNullable().primary();
        table.string('matricula', 100).notNullable().unique('matricula_idx');
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.timestamp('deleted_at');
      })
      .then(() => knex.raw(onUpdateTrigger('employees')));
  });
}
```

my table departament:

```
export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  return knex.schema.hasTable('employee').then(function (exists) {
    if (exists) return;
    return knex.schema // **** udpate
      .createTable('departaments', table => {
        table.uuid('id').notNullable().primary();
        table
          .string('departament_name', 100)
          .notNullable()
          .unique('departament_name');
        table.uuid('manager_id');
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.timestamp('deleted_at');
      })
      .then(() => knex.raw(onUpdateTrigger('departaments')));
  });
}
```

and I also have a more specific question about knexjs migrations: how could I create a clustered index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only half of the answer based on my knowledge of SQL - I haven't used knexjs.

- This answers the first question (referencing a non-PK field in an FK).
- This does not answer the second question - how to set up a clustered index in knexjs.

Theoretically at least, a foreign key *does not have to refer to a primary key* - but it **does** have to refer to a column (or set of columns) with a unique constraint. It is just that in most cases, this is the PK anyway. Here's a reference https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-primary-and-foreign-keys-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#eighth

As your matricula column is unique, it should be fine to be used as reference for a FK. Theoretically. It may depend on what database is being used, and whether knexjs is sophisticated enough to allow it during setup.